# "Error on line 1, column 17: Invalid media type: expected no more input" using OpenAPI Tool

Tags: flutter, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am using the following OpenApi Tool from Github: [OpenApi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator)
It automatically generates classes based on a YAML file. I integrated these classes in my Flutter project and want to use these. I want to use a Method, which makes an Api call to an WebServer called Agent.Workbench.

This was in the README.md generated by the Tool:

```
final api_instance = AdminsApi();

try {
    final result = api_instance.infoGet();
    print(result);
} catch (e) {
    print('Exception when calling AdminsApi->infoGet: $e\n');
}



## Documentation for API Endpoints

All URIs are relative to *https://localhost:8080/api*

Class | Method | HTTP request | Description
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
*AdminsApi* | [**infoGet**](doc//AdminsApi.md#infoget) | **GET** /info | Returns system information
*AdminsApi* | [**loadGet**](doc//AdminsApi.md#loadget) | **GET** /load | Returns the current System load
*AdminsApi* | [**stateGet**](doc//AdminsApi.md#stateget) | **GET** /state | Returns the current AWB state
```

But I get following Error:

```
Error on line 1, column 17: Invalid media type: expected no more input.
  ╷
1 │ application/json, application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I checked the Webserver it does await a application/json and the Client (my Code) too.

This is my Code:

```
Future<void> _testCall() async {
    final api_instance = AdminsApi();
    try {
      final result = api_instance.infoGet();
      print(result);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Exception when calling AdminsApi->infoGet: $e\n');
    }
  }
```

This should print my system information in the Terminal in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown because the string `application/json, application/json; charset=utf-8`  is not a valid media type as defined in [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1).

You can reproduce this error by calling

```dart
MediaType.parse('application/json, application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Instead it should be

```dart
MediaType.parse('application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

As you are using a code-generation framework, we would need to see your input yaml file to see what exactly causes the bad code generation.